# Pass parameters to MySQL script

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL script file named `query1.sql` which contains:

```
select * FROM $(tblName) LIMIT 10;
```

I am in MySQL console, how do I pass the parameter to the script?  This does not forward the variable:

```
mysql> \. query1.sql -v tblName=Users
```

Comment: Following link might help : http://databobjr.blogspot.com/2011/07/passing-parameters-to-mysql-query.html

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use [user variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html) to achieve the behaviour you describe. As you use the variable as a schema identifier, not a data value, you'll have to use a prepared statement so you can compose the query dynamically.

`query1.sql`:

```
SET @query = CONCAT('Select * FROM ', @tblName, ' LIMIT 10');
PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Invoked as

```
mysql> SET @tblName = 'Users'; \. query1.sql
```

Answer (score 13):

The command line call from vidyadhar worked for me, but only with a small modification :

```
mysql -u root -p -e"set @temp=1; `cat /home/mysql/Desktop/a.sql`"
```

Answer (score 11):

This may work for you

```
mysql -u root -p -e"set @temp=1;" < /home/mysql/Desktop/a.sql
```

and

```
mysql> set @temp=some_value;
mysql> source file.sql
```

this almost similar to your problem just try it

Comment: Here the first one does not work. The second one does.

Comment: @silverdr, what problem did you have with the first one?

Comment: @DavidWesby - I am sorry but it was five years ago… I honestly don't remember

Answer (score 2):

For bash scripting:

```
tblName=$1 
searchFor="%something%"

echo "select * FROM $tblName LIMIT 10;
      select * From $tblName where somecolumn like '$searchFor';
" | mysql
```

For powershell:

```
$tblName="MyTable"
$searchFor="%something%"

"select * FROM $tblName LIMIT 10;
  select * From $tblName where somecolumn like '$searchFor';
" | mysql
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @user4150422 above almost worked from me, but `cat` gave me permission issues so I had to use a slight alternative. Weirdly `source` command didn't work in place of cat either, but `\.` did

```
mysql -u root -p -e"set @temp=1; `\. /home/mysql/Desktop/a.sql`"
```

Answer (score 0):

The advanced solution for use bash variables via mysql variables like `@tblName` in order to INSERT values into specific table:

The core file insert.preps included *prepared statements* procedural (SET > PREPARE > EXECUTE > DEALLOCATE):

```
SET @query = CONCAT("INSERT INTO ", @tblName, " (id, time, file, status) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
SET @id = '0';
EXECUTE stmt USING @id, @time, @file, @status;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

*`SET @id = '0';` in the file predefined because `id` is usually is `INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY`. It will auto-assign proper `id` for all lines.

Invoking it in the shell or in bash script with using variables:

```
mysql --defaults-extra-file=<(echo $'[client]\npassword='"$db_password") --user=$db_user $db_name -e "
     SET @tblName = '$table';
     SET @time = '$timeStamp';
     SET @file = '$file';
     SET @status = '$status';
`cat /path/to/insert.preps`"
```