# Pass parameter from Batch file to MYSQL script

Tags: mysql, windows, batch-file, parameters

I'm having a really hard time believing this question has never been asked before, it MUST be! I'm working on a batch file that needs to run some sql commands. All tutorials explaining this DO NOT WORK (referring to this link:[Pass parameters to sql script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14098222/pass-parameters-to-sql-script) that someone will undoubtedly mention)! I've tried other posts on this site verbatim and still nothing is working.

The way I see it, there are two ways I can approach this:
1. Either figure out how to call my basic MYSQL script and specify a parameter or..
2. Find an equivalent "USE ;" command that works in batch

My Batch file so far:

```
:START
@ECHO off

:Set_User
set usrCode = 0

mysql -u root SET @usrCode = '0'; \. caller.sql
```

Simply put, I want to pass 'usrCode' to my MYSQL script 'caller.sql' which looks like this:

```
USE `my_db`;
CALL collect_mismatch(@usrCode);
```

I know that procedures are a whole other topic to get into, but assume that the procedure is working just fine. I just can't get my parameter from Batch to MYSQL.

Ideally I would like to have the 'USE' & 'CALL' commands in my Batch file, but I can't find anything that let's me select a database in Batch before CALLing my procedure. That's when I tried the above link which boasts a simple command line entry and you're off to the races, but it isn't the case.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Remove spaces in your SET Batch command: `set usrCode=0`

Comment: Haha, your comment ended up helping me out in the end. I tried everything in the answer below and totally forgot about the Batch variable rules. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work;

```
echo SET @usrCode = '0'; > params.sql
type params.sql caller.sql | mysql -u root dbname
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your speedy reply! :) Only question I have, because I want to learn from stuff like this. What is the function of the " | " between the type command and calling mysql?

Comment: It's a pipe, it sends the printed data on the left (stdout) to the input stream of the right (stdin).

Comment: @harvey works great for one argument, how to do it for multiple arguments? Thanks