# How to passe parameters from batch(.bat) to trigger in a mySql file?

Tags: mysql, batch-file, triggers

I have to files :batchFile.bat and sqlFile.sql

The batchFile.bat contains this code :

```
@echo OFF
set host=localhost
set user=root
set pass=123
set dbname=db_prod
set dbname_hist=db_prod_hist
mysql -u %user% -h %host% -D %dbname% -p%pass% -v < sqlFile.sql
```

The sqlFile.sql contains this code :

```
delimiter //
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS tri_tableA1//
CREATE TRIGGER tri_tableA1
AFTER INSERT ON tableA1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO *{dbname_hist}*.tableA1 (id,    prixAchatUnitaireHT, montantAchat,  duree) 
select NEW.id,  NEW.prixAchatUnitaireHT,    NEW.montantAchat,   NEW.duree; 
END//
delimiter ;
```

My question is: how can i passe the **{dbname_hist}** parameter from the .bat file to .sql file ?!

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14098222/pass-parameters-to-sql-script).

Comment: I tried this [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14098222/pass-parameters-to-sql-script) , it doesn't work !.