# SQL Query From Two Tables And Several Rows

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 2 tables.

The fisrt: Users
[image]

The second: Messages
[image]

My tables relationships:

[image]

**My problem is:** I need a query that returns me the all the Messages for reciver (the parameter) and the MessageSenderID and MessageReciverID as name, not as id.

my query:

```
SELECT Message.MessageID, Message.MessageSubject, Message.MessageContent,
       u1.UserFisrtName + '' + u1.UserLastName AS Sender1,
       u2.UserFisrtName + '' + u2.UserLastName AS Reciver1
FROM Users AS u1,
     Users AS u2,
     Messages
WHERE u1.UserID = Message.MessageSenderID
  AND u2.UserID = Message.UserID
  AND u2.UserID = ***userid***
```

The error is:

> no value given for one or more required parameters.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Your query is invalid standard SQL. Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Do you have any example for that?
I am using Access 2016 for shcool project

Comment: Are MessageSenderID and MessageReceiverID both foreign keys?

Comment: NO, the MessageReciverID is the fk (look at the picture). But the MessageSenderID is not a fk but include data from Users table (not with relationships)

Comment: You have a typo there: `UserFisrtName` is `UserFirstName` in the Users table. My tip of the day: use the query designer.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a JOIN statement

```
SELECT * FROM messages
JOIN user u1 ON (u1.id = message.MessageSenderID)
JOIN user u2 ON (u2.id = message.essageReciverID)
```

More info on Join: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx

For the parameter problem see this question: [Pass parameters to sql script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14098222/pass-parameters-to-sql-script)

The parameter can be used as following:

```
WHERE u2.id = @userid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Messages.MessageID, Messages.MessageSubject, Messages.MessageContent,
       s.UserFisrtName & ' ' & s.UserLastName AS Sender,
       r.UserFisrtName & ' ' & r.UserLastName AS Reciver
FROM (Messages
INNER JOIN Users AS s ON s.UserID = Messages.MessageSenderID)
INNER JOIN Users AS r ON r.UserID = Messages.MessageReciverID
WHERE r.UserID = **userid**;
```

Comment: Its giving me `No value given for one or more required parameters` error

Comment: Have you given the value of **userid** at:
`WHERE r.UserID = **userid**;`

Comment: use `INNER JOIN` instead of simple `JOIN`