# Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm using ms-access for school project, and i need to get data from two table.

I tried to do this sql query:

```
SELECT m.MessageID, m.MessageSubject, m.MessageContent, m.MessageIsRead, 
    m.MessageSendDate, m.MessageDeletedBy,
    s.UserFisrtName + '' + s.UserLastName AS Sender,
    r.UserFisrtName + '' + r.UserLastName AS Reciver
FROM Messages m
INNER JOIN Users AS s ON s.UserID = m.MessageSenderID
INNER JOIN Users AS r ON r.UserID = m.MessageReciverID
```

I get an error:

`Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression &#39;s.UserID = m.MessageSenderID INNER JOIN Users AS r ON r.UserID = m.MessageReciverI&#39;`

I already have a problem with this issue [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46462536/sql-query-from-two-tables-and-several-rows/46462908)

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You code does not look like MS Access.  I would expect:

```
SELECT m.MessageID, m.MessageSubject, m.MessageContent, m.MessageIsRead, 
       m.MessageSendDate, m.MessageDeletedBy,
       (s.UserFirstName & s.UserLastName) AS Sender,
       (r.UserFirstName & r.UserLastName) AS Reciver
FROM (Messages as m INNER JOIN
      Users as s
      ON s.UserID = m.MessageSenderID
     ) INNER JOIN
     Users as r
     ON r.UserID = m.MessageReciverID;
```

There is no reason to put an empty string between two names.  If you want to put a space, for instance, then it would look like:

```
       (s.UserFisrtName & " " & s.UserLastName) AS Sender,
```

Comment: Its return: `No value given for one or more required parameters`

Comment: @MrLord ... so you researched that message and fixed it, right?

Comment: Yes I researched, but I couldn't find the the problem

Comment: Same typo as in the first question: `UserFisrtName` should be `UserFirstName`. @MrLord