# How do I enter parameters in my SQL command?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a function where I set a few parameters, these parameters I want to pass on later in my SQL query as a variable.

My goal is not to write an extra function for every color I have in my game.

I want a function and whenever I enter the parameters it should be processed in my SQL query.

```
 public function setVillageRes(int $villageID, int $ownerID, $res, $fabrik){
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM village WHERE villageID = ? AND ownerID = ?");
        $stmt->execute([$villageID, $ownerID]);
        $result = $stmt->fetch();

        if(is_array($result)){

            $sql = "UPDATE village SET `$res` = ? WHERE `$villageID` = ? AND `$fabrik` = ?";
            $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute([$res, $villageID, $fabrik]);

        } else {
            return "RE-3001";
        }
    }
```

Comment: How can I solve this?

Comment: your update query makes no sense `$villageID` = ? would result in something like 1=1 which is always true, so why do you try to substitute the columnnames?

Comment: Is this what oyu want ?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14098222/pass-parameters-to-mysql-script

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass parameters to MySQL script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14098222/pass-parameters-to-mysql-script)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use the variables in the `UPDATE` query, use the column names.

```
$sql = "UPDATE village SET `res` = ? WHERE `villageID` = ? AND `fabrik` = ?";
```